# Prior to Cloud City, did Vader know that Han and Leia were "friends" of Luke?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

By the time we see the Cloud City in *The Empire Strikes Back*, it clear that the heroes know that Luke, Leia, and Han have special feelings for each other that go beyond being comrades in the rebellion.  Obi-Wan claims that this is the reason why Vader tortures Han [and Leia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126647/102339):

> BEN: It is you and your abilities the Emperor wants.  that is why your 
>   friends are made to suffer.

**But at that time does Vader**<sup>1</sup> ***actually know* that Luke is friends**<sup>2</sup> **with Han and Leia?**

<sup>1</sup> possibly through the Emperor or some other member of the Empire.

<sup>2</sup> not just comrades or someone who was conveniently present.

- The [screenplay](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) of *The Empire Strikes Back* uses the words "friend/friends/friendly" 23 times, but *never by Vader or any other member of the Empire*.
- Being a secretive organization, the rebellion would try to keep the personal relationships of its members hidden from the Empire.  Such information could otherwise be used to compromise people.
- The Empire could reasonably assume that Luke would have strong feelings towards *any* of his comrades.
- Leia *is* an excellent choice as a lure, but for reasons that have nothing to do with friendship.  As a leader of the rebellion, any rebel will have strong feelings to protect her.  She has also proven to Vader in *A New Hope* that she is an effective lure for Jedi (Obi-Wan).  But these reasons have nothing to do with friendship.
- Vader didn't actively choose who would be captured; rather, he took advantage of an opportunity.  The capture of the *Millenium Falcon* is by circumstance (failure of the hyperdrive), rather than by Vader's planning.  Similarly, Leia's presence on the *Falcon* is by circumstance, not by Vader's planning.
- If Vader *could* have chosen a victim to lure Luke, Wedge Antilles would outwardly appear to be a better choice than Han.  Both men saved Luke's life in the battle of Yavin.  However, Wedge was also Luke's wingman in that battle.  In addition, Luke and Wedge are both loyal to the rebellion, Han isn't.
- If the answer is "no", then this would once again be a case of Obi-Wan telling Luke things that are "true, from a certain perspective."

Comment: Vader knows the *Millenium Falcon* is associated with Luke. He might know the *Falcon* killed his wingman at the Battle of Yavin and saw the *Falcon* in person in the Battle of Hoth. It sort of seems like he thinks Luke is actually on the *Falcon*, but for whatever reason, by the time he gets to Cloud City, Lando probably told Vader what he knows about the owner of the *Falcon*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - "*“Our pursuit ships have sighted the Millennium Falcon, my lord. It has entered an asteroid field.” “Asteroids don’t concern me, Admiral,” Vader said as he slowly clenched his fist. “I want that ship, not excuses. How long until you will have Skywalker and the others in the Millennium Falcon?”* (ESB - Novelisation) - Vader is ***definitely*** under the impression that Luke is on board the ship.

Comment: if you consider what is currently canon, then yes. In the canon Marvel comics, the trio are all over the place interacting with and confounding Imperial plans between ANH and Empire

Answer (score 4):

Based on the fact that they arrived on cloud city together, something as little as security footage or a prick in the force would set Vader off to their comradeship. It's entirely possible that they were tracked the whole time Lando was with them (if I was Vader I would), so they would be seen together. Also, Vader seems to be aware about Luke being on the Millennium Falcon.

Comment: Or Boba Fett.  Remember, he was the one who followed the *Falcon* to Bespin and turned them in to Vader.  These are all interesting plot devices, but can we show that they informed Vader about their friendship?

Comment: Good point @DrSheldon. Bounty hunters go for money. It would make sense to infer that Vader would just hand them some more credits and get more information.

Answer (score 2):

The Millenium Falcon is the key. It was the Ship that Luke was on aboard the Death Star, it was the ship that saved Luke during the battle of Yavin. While you can look at Wedge, the Falcon stands out because it was out of place, it wasn't meant to be there (also Vader probably isn't too fond of the ship). It was at Hoth and Vader seems to at least suspect his son may be on board.