# Since when has Darth Vader had a sense of humor?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, rogue-one

After Force-choking Director Krennic, Darth Vader makes the comment

> *Be careful not to **choke** on your aspirations, Director.*

**This comment displays a sense of humor that seems entirely out of character for him. Is it ever explained in-universe?**

[image]

Comment: He is a father, so the dad jokes have to come at some point.

Comment: I'd also argue that Vader's "I find your lack of faith disturbing" comment after force choking Motti is a form of subtler humor.

Comment: I thought it was "aspirations", not "ambition".

Comment: @Deepak I'm pretty sure it is aspirations, which doubles the pun factor.

Comment: @Coxy Yes, I originally had a longer comment in mind to explain the (rather icky) added medical pun factor, but I decided to keep it short. :)

Comment: The whole reason Vader wears that black mask is to cover up his Groucho Marx joke glasses.

Comment: @Wossname In *Lego Star Wars*, you can make it so that everybody, including Darth Vader and the droids, are wearing Groucho Marx joke glasses with mustaches!

Comment: "He is not as forgiving as I am" - Vader referring to the Emperor when speaking to Moff Jerjerrod about Death Star II construction completeness. Humorous because, as we know from Eps. IV and V, Vader's just not really forgiving AT ALL.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer - I've added that to my answer. You're right. It's quite subtle but he's clearly making that point.

Comment: @RogueJedi, that reminds me of this book, Darth Vader and Son, that someone gave me as a present when I became a dad.  http://amzn.to/2i2sxq8

Comment: http://www.cracked.com/article_24495_6-underappreciated-moments-pop-cultural-bad-assery.html  point #6 -- Darth Vader Is A Stone-Cold, Mic-Dropping Death Machine -- If the comics are still considered canon.

Comment: He's always had a sense of humor, just like [Dorca Vorbarra](http://vorkosigan.wikia.com/wiki/Vorloupulous's_Law).

Comment: @Deepak - it was indeed "aspirations". See edit.

Comment: I haven't looked at anything here, but I just wanted to say thank you so much for hiding the spoilers. It was kind of you.

Comment: Does *Ani* count as canon?

Comment: When shooting at Luke in the trench he says "The force is strong with this one" can be a humorous exasperation, not a statement of fact, though apparently true anyway.

Comment: I've removed the spoiler tag. The choking scene was in the trailer and it's not especially plot-relevant.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Vader has quite a *dry* sense of humour and can often be found quipping at mildly inappropriate moments, especially when choking people, which he really seems to enjoy.

One assumes this is a habit he's picked up from his mentor Obi-Wan "*[so uncivilised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0BciHfsU7k)*" Kenobi.

## A New Hope

> **VADER:** *I find your lack of faith disturbing* [as he's choking Motti]

### Empire Strikes Back

> **VADER:** *Apology accepted, Captain Needa.* [As he's choking Needa]

and

> **VADER:** *We would be honored if you would join us.* [Inviting Leia, Han and Chewie to dine with him after capturing them]

and

> **VADER:** *Perhaps you think you're being treated unfairly.* [As Lando complains about the deal he's made being changed]

### Return of the Jedi

> **VADER:** *Perhaps I can find new ways to motivate them.* [When told that the construction crews are working at full capacity]

and

> **VADER:** *The Emperor is not as forgiving as I am.* [as a not-so veiled threat]

---

In the [Revenge of the Sith novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) he's even quippier when dealing with the Separatist leadership, indulging in some word play and even a pun or two.

> *“We were promised a reward,” she gasped. “A h-h-handsome reward“
>
>   "I am your reward,” the Sith Lord said. “You don’t find me handsome?”*
>
> ...
>
> *“You fought a war to destroy the Jedi.” Vader stood above the
>   shivering Neimoidian, smiling down upon him, then fed him half a meter
>   of plasma. “Congratulations on your success.”*
>
> ...
>
> *The head of the Techno Union turned at his approach, cringing, arms
>   lifted to shield his faceplate from the flames in the dragon’s eyes.
>   “Please, I’ll give you anything. Anything you want!”*
>   *The blade flashed twice; Tambor’s arms fell to the floor, followed by
>   his head. “Thank you.”*
>
> ...
>
> *“The war is over-Lord Sidious promised-he promised we would be left in
>   peace …”
>
>   “His transmission was garbled.” The blade came up. “He
>   promised you would be left in pieces.”*

and again in [Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)) when killing Phoca Soot in front of a group of Coruscanti gangsters and criminals.

> *His eyes glazed over and his red skin began to pale; then his arms
>   flew back from his chest as if in an act of desperate supplication,
>   and he tipped backward, the left side of his head slamming hard
>   against the blood-slicked floor.*
>
> *For a long moment, Vader’s breathing was the only sound intruding on
>   the silence. Without bothering to gaze on his handiwork, the Dark Lord
>   finally said: “Perhaps this is a good place to conclude our assembly.
>   Unless any of you have questions?”*

### Marvel: [Star Wars #2](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/52645/star_wars_2015_2)

[image]

Comment: That novelization pun is infinitely worse than the one is *Rogue One*.

Comment: @RogueJedi - There are some more...

Comment: I don't find any of the movie quotes funny. IMHO they are rather blatant displays of power, meant to intimidate everyone within hearing range. And indeed they do intimidate.

Comment: @Agent_L - Oh come on. "Apology accepted" is hilarious.

Comment: @Valorum Hilarious to you, because you're safe in your cinema seat. If Vader would reject his apology, that would leave a sliver of hope that his apology was just not good enough. "Apology accepted" sends clear message. To characters on screen it means that there is no escape from summary execution. If you fail once, then whatever you do, you'll still end up dead. There is nothing even remotely funny here, it's pure terror.

Comment: @Agent_L: It’s not important whether you find them funny. As long as Vader has his fun. And if you ever meet him, don’t tell him that you think he isn’t funny…

Comment: @Holger - Precisely this. He says it **to himself** rather than to impress those around him. If you could see under his mask he'd be smirking.

Comment: But Original Trilogy Vader doesn't make _puns_. Even if he made some twenty years prior, it would be more in character during Rogue One to show a punless sense of dry humor as in the Original Trilogy which begins within seconds to hours of the end of Rogue One.

Comment: @Agent_L I don't think they're meant to make you laugh, but rather to show that Vader cares little enough about his brutality toward people who disrespect or fail him to make jokes during/after. I would argue that if the jokes actually make you laugh, that would take away from what they're meant to accomplish.

Comment: I always recognized Vader as being witty, even when I was a kid.

Comment: @Holger - "So you think I'm **funny**? Funny **HOW?** How am I funny, what is so funny about me?" - Vader

Comment: @Hannover Fist: I said, “don’t tell him that you think he isn’t funny”. I did not say “Tell him, he is funny”. The best strategy is to avoid this topic. Or well, to avoid talking with him in general. Avoid being in listening range. Of any media.

Comment: Do not say, he isn't funny. Don't say, he is funny either. Do not say anything at all. Do not even think of it. Just do your job and pray for mercy.

Comment: @Agent_L I think the message it sends is that Vader is a guy who may be seem harsh, but after he is done executing what he believes is a fair punishment, you can rest calm because he is willing to move forward and forget about the incident (for example he never mentioned the issue to Needa again). He is certainly a strict guy, but a fair one; you just need to know him to get along well. And he is not that difficult to fool (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jdQqjcsfC8)

Comment: @Devsman You seem to be implying that punning cannot be done dryly (a "punless sense of dry humor").   I'll warn you that it can and often is O_O

Comment: @goldilocks Not at all. No more so than I would be implying that green grass can not be long by describing "short green grass."

Comment: @HannoverFist That Goodfellas reference seems to have whizzed over some people's heads like the Millennium Falcon, but I appreciated it.

Comment: Since those lines pretty clearly show original trilogy Vader to possess a rather laconic wit, and the Rogue One line...doesn't, the question "Since when has Darth Vader had a sense of humor?" can be answered quite precisely.   He developed a sense of humor sometime over the course of the week or so between the relevant scenes in Rogue One and New Hope.

Comment: “The war is over-Lord Sidious promised-he promised we would be left in peace …” “His transmission was garbled.” The blade came up. “He promised you would be left in pieces.” --- This pun only works if English is being spoken in the Star Wars galaxy, otherwise what are the chances the words "piece" and "peace" would sound identical in an alien language?

Comment: @robert - Puns tend to work quite well in most languages. ***Laissé en paix*** (Left in peace) = ***Lessez en pées*** (Unleash the sword). But you're right, Basic tends to get treated like English.

Comment: I didn't realize Vader was James Bond

Answer (score 42):

Since his days as annoying, whining, but deadpan-snarking Padawan (and he learned the snark from Obi-Wan, if nothing else).

*ROTS*

> General Grievous, You're Shorter Than I Expected.
>
> Anakin: Under the circumstances, I'd say the ability to pilot this thing is irrelevant.
>
> Obi Wan: Wait a minute, how did this happen? We're smarter than this!
>   Anakin: Apparently not.
>
> Obi-Wan: Oh Anakin, where is your lightsaber?
>   Anakin: **I know exactly where it is. *pointing at a battle droid* It's right there**.
>   Obi-Wan: How could you let this happen?
>   Anakin: Hey, he's got your lightsaber too, you know.
>   Obi-Wan: I really don't think that's the point.
>   Anakin: This weapon is your life, Obi-Wan!
>   Obi-Wan: Yes, alright, you've made your point.
>
> OBI-WAN: Oh, so all of a sudden it's my fault.
>   ANAKIN: You're the Master. I'm just a hero.

***AOTC***

> Dooku: That was brave, boy, but foolish. I would have thought you'd have learned your lesson.
>   Anakin: I'm a slow learner.

Comment: Darth Vader is Anakin? ***SPOILER!*** :-P

Comment: He's a lot quippier in the original trilogy. They even trimmed out a lot of the funnies because the tone went too far toward comedy; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYR0zuQQ3AE

Comment: @Valorum - But... in the original trilogy... **he doesn't have a time machine**!!! You can't explain his sense of humor in Rogue One by OT, in-universe :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I was explaining that he's got a pretty consistent sense of humour from Rogue One onwards and that making jokes is well in character for him.

Comment: @Valorum - stop spoiling ***my*** snark with your comprehensive answers :)

Comment: I think you may have answered a slightly different question. He's not asking where Vader's sense of humour comes from, he's asking whether it's appropriate for the character

Comment: @Valorum - (1) The subject asks "**Since when** has Darth Vader had a sense of humor?". (2) I answered "where from" as well - from Obi-Wan, in the very first paragraph)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I read it slightly different. More like "***What gives? Vader doesn't have a sense of humour, does he?***"

Comment: @Valorum - that's a valid interpretation as well.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Thanks for reminding us all #WinterBash2016 is on!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Laugh all you want, but I forget to tell that to my wife before watching the prequels and lack of this knowledge ruined them for her.

Comment: @Agent_L that can't have been the only thing :D

Comment: @Gusdor That's the only thing she refuses to forgive me : )

Comment: @Agent_L how did that "ruin" them for her?

Comment: @Yakk No idea. I don't think a person who knew that Anakin is Vader can get into the mindset of someone not knowing.

Comment: That last line could just as easily be Philip J. Fry

Answer (score 9):

It seems pretty fitting actually, considering his attitude in the prequel trilogy, then his rogue one quips, then how much darker, dry, and sadistic his remarks become in the OT. The stress of being a sith Lord will take the piss out of even the cockiest of smartass. If phantom menace Anakin starts the spectrum and return of Jedi Vader ends it, it's pretty clear he's always been a smartass and the stress of a job in government made him a grouchy old curmudgeon.

Comment: Actually, I think you'll find that due to the ... accident ... his suit has to take the piss constantly.

Comment: Except A New Hope is set immediately after Rogue One.