# Do the Sith have a sense of humor, do they laugh?

Tags: star-wars, sith

I know that this question is similar to asking whether "Dementors" in Harry Potter can laugh or smile, but still, in the canon do the Sith ever laugh, maybe at least smile? Do they understand jokes and do they have a sense of humor?

Comment: *laughs in Palpatine*

Comment: @Shreedhar Wasn't he resembling a laugh?

Comment: [Very closely related, possible duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147765/58193).

Comment: Pre-burnt Palpatine did smile.. cunning smiles wicked ones too... Remember his time with Anakin in the Godawful prequels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147765/101407

Comment: The Emperor certainly yucked it up as he roasted Luke...

Comment: Palpatine is always laughing. He's a cheerful fella

Comment: I don't remember a sith ever telling jokes or really laughing like normal people do.

Comment: @SovereignSun - "Apology Accepted" is bloody hilarious

Comment: "Be careful not to *choke* on your aspirations" from Lord Vader when he's Force-choking someone is at least snicker-worthy wordplay if not an outright joke.

Comment: @DavidW - I'm tempted to close this as a dupe. Vader is a Sith and certainly has a sense of humour.

Comment: Any competent bad guy knows the value of a maniacal laugh ...

Answer (score 7):

In Return of the Jedi, there are several instances where Palpatine is either laughing or smiling on the Death Star.  He also does this in the Clone Wars, when he fights Darth Maul and Savage Opress.

As far as jokes, in Revenge of the Sith, Dooku responds to Anakin's "My powers have doubled since we last met" with "Twice the pride, double the fall".  In Rogue One, Vader says "Be careful not to choke on your aspirations" as he is force choking Krennic.

There are likely more examples if you dig through all the material and look for them but these are the ones that stood out the most for me.